# c# continue and complete executing code after wpf application exit

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**Background:** I am working on a c# WPF application where, at some stage, user instructs the application to do some *work*. The *work* may take substantial amount of time and the user may not wish for the work to be completed and may exit the WPF application - with the intention of returning at a later time to review the results - which the application gets from a DB.

**Question:**  Looking for is a way for the WPF application to finish the *work* - regardless of whether the WPF application has exited or not.

**Choice 1:** I could write a worker application that does the *work* - and start a process from my WPF application that executes this worker application.

**Choice 2:** Spawn a thread / backgroundwoker that does the *work*. This would have the additional advantage of presenting the results to the user, should the application still be active.

I would much prefer choice 2, if it were feasible. Would appreciate any advice - other alternatives, things to watch, relevant links etc. Almost all links I have seen are focused on successfully terminating threads prior to application exit, and none that I have found talks of the opposite scenario.

Comment: If you exit the application, all its threads will be killed. Can the user not just minimize the app?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at windows service, your application will not continue once it's closed. Or even have a local web server that can do the work and it can update the wpf app through SignalR when the work is done.

Comment: Indeed, Windows service is another option. I am not optimistic about the thread route it is not likely to work, as Blogbeard says.